# How can I hide command prompt window when Selenium launches google chrome portable?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, command-prompt

I have chrome browser version 113 installed on my computer, and I also have google chrome portable version 114 saved on the machine. I coded Selenium to launch the chrome portable, and it works no problem, but it also opens up the command prompt window.

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqyEn.jpg)

my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import subprocess
import os

current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
driver_path = os.path.join(current_directory, "chromedriver.exe")
chrome_path = os.path.join(current_directory, "GoogleChromePortable_114.0.5735.91\GoogleChromePortable.exe")
profile_path = os.path.join(current_directory, "GoogleChromePortable_114.0.5735.91\Data\profile\Default")
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=" + profile_path)

chrome_service = Service(driver_path)
chrome_service.creation_flags = subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW

chrome_options.binary_location = chrome_path
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,service=chrome_service)
```

Is there anyway to hide the command prompt window? I have tried 'chrome_service.creation_flags = subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW', but no luck.

Comment: never mind, I think I figured it out. Here is the solution, do not binary locate the "GoogleChromePortable.exe" in the GoogleChromePortable folder. Correct binary file's path is "\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe"

Comment: Yes, you can also see that in my repo where my answer already mentioned and it is able to handle both portable and installation version situations.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **HideCommandPromptWindow** property of your **chrome_service** (in C#), you can seek the corresponding name in python.

```
chrome_service.HideCommandPromptWindow =true
```

You can refer to my repo [TextForCtext](https://github.com/oscarsun72/TextForCtext/blob/9b3d3f7b000752d590c87c1b9576f55422ceda86/WindowsFormsApp1/Browser.cs#L503) code.